# Create a rule to restrict user access to shared account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a database where user 1,2... share the same "account" but with different privileges.

So them both users are able to access the object A from account C instead of each user having his/her account.

The database is structured like this:

```js
Users{
  uuid1 {
    uuid:1234
      account:1
  },
  uuid2 {
      uuid:12345
      account:1
  }
  ...
}
```

where uuid1 = 1234 and uuid2 = 12345 on this sample

And a custom object:

```js
Object {
  uuid1 {
      Ubject {
        id1 {}
        id2 {}
        ...
      }
  uuid2 {}
  ...
}
```

So a real path to a user object is like this:

```js
/Users/IiagiaYij
```

and a real path to an object is like this:

```js
/Object/IiagiaYij/Object/LDCK
/Object/IiagiaYij/Object/XY34
```

I tried the above rule:

```js
rules_version = '2';
function isSignedIn() {
  return request.auth != null;
}

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isAdmin(uid) {
      return uid == "VaFd";
    }
    function getUserData(userID) {
      return get(/databases/(default)/documents/Users/$(userID)).data;
    }
    match /{document=**}/{documentID} {
      allow read, write: if isSignedIn() && (isAdmin(request.auth.uid) || getUserData(request.auth.uid).account == documentID)
    }
  }
}
```

For documents like "user" it works, as documentID returns "IiagiaYij", but for Object not, as documentID returns "LDCK"

Here, it's important to know that the object returned from "LDCK" doesn't have the account id as one of the keys.

Is there any way to compose a rule without the account id on the document?